# Displaying Google Ads on dynamically loaded htmls

Tags: ads

We have an account with Google Adsense and the ads work well for our site. Now we have planned to rewrite our website to make it more dynamic.
The ads are no longer working for the new site when tested.

Here is our design of the website. Once we load the home page,we click on a link to load the html page in a particular section of the jsp.
 Its an Ajax call and the Ajax response is the html which has to be displayed.The html is now set inside a  tag using the tag's innerHTML method.

The html has the ad script embedded in it.Even if it is not an Ajax call, the ads do not work.
We tried replacing the  with an  and embedding the html code inside the . The ads do work, but we have to move the code which we wrote in the jsp to the htmls which is a very tedious task.Also the  is not working in Google Chrome. We can see the ads being displayed in a static html as opposed to how we are displaying it in the website.

Please kindly assist us with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert javascript code with innerHTML. It is going to behave as inner content, not as javascript. I mean it won't be executed.

Instead of that you may use an iframe and put your adsense code there. If you want, you can create an iframe with javascript and then write inside of that with document.write(). As an iframe has a different instance of *document* it will be asyncronichous.